# Best way to modify behaviour of a setter for an attribute of a class which in itself is an attribute of another class?

Tags: python

Sorry for the confusing title. My problem looks as following:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.flags = Flags()
        self.subclasses = [list of B objects]

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.flags = Flags()

class Flags():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = False
```

I want to be able to modify the value of the flag in A, which in turn adjusts all the flag values of the list of B objects. In my original soultion I simply set the value of the flag as an attribute of class A and then overwrote the setter with @property and @value.setter, my question is if it is also possible to do it the way described above.

Comment: In your code, `Flags()` needs to be `Flag()`.

Comment: Please start with valid class definitions; what you have right now aren't.

Comment: thank you for your quick replies. I just adjusted my post accordingly

Comment: post the context where you "modify the value of the flag in A"

Comment: The flag value is modified by instantiating class A and simply calling a.flags.value=True or False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want using a descriptor:

```
class Flag:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = False
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.value = value
        if isinstance(obj, A):
            for scl in obj.subclasses:
                scl.flag = value
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        return self.value


class B:
    flag = Flag()
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"B: {self.flag}"

class A:
    flag = Flag()
    def __init__(self, bs):
        self.subclasses = list(bs)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A: {self.flag}"



bs = [B() for _ in range(7)]
a = A(bs)
```

The `__repr__` methods are just for demonstration:

```
>>> a
A: True
>>> a.subclasses
[B: False, B: False, B: False, B: False, B: False, B: False, B: False]
>>> a.flag = True
A: True
>>> a.subclasses
[B: True, B: True, B: True, B: True, B: True, B: True, B: True]
```

---

If you want to have a dynamic number of flags that all have this effect, you could use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` on the descriptor:

```
class Flags:
    def __init__(self):
        self._storage = {}
        self._obj = None
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        self._obj = instance
        return self
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr.startswith("_"):
            return super().__setattr__(attr, value)
        self._storage[attr] = value
        if hasattr(self._obj, "subclasses"):
            for sub in self._obj.subclasses:
                setattr(sub.flag, attr, value)
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self._storage[attr]


class B:
    flags = Flags()

class A:
    flags = Flags()
    def __init__(self, bs):
        self.subclasses = list(bs)
```

Usage:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> a = A([b])
>>> a.flags.foo = "bar"
>>> b.flags.foo
"bar"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this also work for example if there were multiple attributes in the flag class? Is it possible to say a.flags.value_a = True and have this propagate to all the subclasses of a? Where does the obj object in the flags class come from?

Comment: It would be possible, yes. You could implement the properties on the `Flag` class, or even implement `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` on `Flag` to do it with a dynamic list of flag attributes. If you want to be able to do `a.flag.value = ...` would probably be to implement `__set_name__` to remember the instance the descriptor is bound to.

Comment: Hey, I have been trying to implement your solution the way you described it but am having some issues, specifically with accessing the superclass from the setattr and getattr functions the way you can access them in __set__, I assume that's what __set_name__ is for? Could you maybe show me how to use __set_name__ to achieve the same result?